# Рисование графиков

Tags: java

Здраствуйте, я начинаю изучать построение графического интерфейса в Java и передо мной стоит такое задание: нужно построить графики некоторых маршурутов(тоесть просто соединить между собой некоторые точки на оси координат X,Y) по нажатию соответствующей кнопки на форме. Как это проще и короче всего сделать? Если не составит труда, покажите на маленьком примере.

Answer (score 1):

Рисуем с помощью [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics g = getGraphics();
      g.drawLine(0, 1, 2, 3);

 }
```

Надо добавить этот код, например, в [апплет](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawline.htm) и смотреть, что получилось.

Для построения маршрута вводите в форму массив координат (пары чисел), по нажатию кнопки считываете и прорисовываете в цикле.

Comment: хорошо, а вот как именно нарисовать графики координат, а потом маршруты на этих графиках? Можете чтото подсказать?

Comment: рисуем 2 линии (х, у) (drawLine), а внутри рисуем еще линии (drawLine), где g.drawLine(х1, х2, у1, у2)

Comment: идею я понял, но чтобы реализовать её, чувствую, нужно подучить графический интерфейс java. Спасибо!

Comment: График нарисовал, но как на нем нарисовать С ДРУГОГО КЛАССА или ПАКЕТА?

Comment: Блин, как тут код добавить???????